# Convert Excel string to php readable string

Tags: php, excel

I have a string in my excel file i want to import into my php file. The string in my excel is like this

```
"7.60758968 5.18041206 474.02691650390625 3.216; 7.60758992 5.18041221 474.0428466796875 3.216; 7.60758994 5.1804122 474.05999755859375 3.216; 7.60758999 5.18041216 474.0733642578125 3.216; 7.60763331 5.18028509 0.0 0.0; 7.60758968 5.18041206 474.02691650390625 3.216"
```

But when i import it into my php file i get this format

"*x002D_6.952759226315581_x0020_26.355571523308754_x0020_0.0_x0020_0.0_x003B__x0020*-6.952759226315581_x0020_26.355571523308754_x0020_0.0_x0020_0.0_x003B__x0020_-12.33183769136499_x0020_23.822881914675232_x0020_0.0_x0020_0.0_x003B__x0020_-6.952759226315581_x0020_26.355571523308754_x0020_0.0_x0020_0.0"

How can i convert it back to a readable string as it was in the excel file?

EDIT: i am using a package FastExcel to import the excel file.

```
$reg_users = FastExcel::import($file, function ($line) {

        dd( $line['farm_map_farm_geoshape']);
        $area = SizeCalculation::calculateDistance($line['farm_map_farm_geoshape']);

        return DirtyData::create([
            'geopoint_Latitude' => $line['geopoint_Latitude'],
            'geopoint_Accuracy' => $line['geopoint_Accuracy'],
            'geopoint_Altitude' => $line['geopoint_Altitude'],
            'geopoint_Longitude' => $line['geopoint_Longitude'],
            'deviceid' => $line['deviceid'],
            'area' => $area,
            'farmer_data_first_name' => $line['farmer_data_first_name'],
            'farmer_data_last_name' => $line['farmer_data_last_name'],
            'farm_data_state' => $line['farm_data_state'],
            'farm_data_lga' => $line['farm_data_lga']
        ]);
    });
```

Comment: How are you converting 7.60... to 6.95...  ??  Why not show the examples with the SAME data on both places?  (Also show some PHP code, because that is where the error is....)

Comment: Show your code. How to you import an Excel file into PHP?

Comment: @Luuk they are just 4 gps coordinates alongside altitude and accuracy . I have edited my code to show how i imported it.

Comment: @MarkusZeller i have edited my code

Comment: Is that the var_dump() of the $line?

Comment: @Markus Zeller yes that's it